# iMac-brand new disconnected from wireless keyboard and mouse

Tags: mac

Both my wireless keypad and my magic mouse are flashing green as the bluetooth connection has been lost. How do I give commands to the iMac to restore the bluetooth connection when I cannot use the keyboard (not connected) or the mouse (not connected) to do so? How does one work the iMac without a keyboard or mouse?

Comment: One takes a wired keyboard and uses that to restore the connection.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest option is to obtain and connect a wired keyboard and a wired mouse.